# Android ActionBarSherlock duplicated menu button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I use `ActionBarSherlock` on my app compiled with `Android 4.0.3`.
When testing on my device running `JellyBean 4.2.1`, I can see the overflow icon both in the `ActionBar` and in the bottom `buttons` bar.

See `Screenshot`.

How can the bottom `overflow` button be removed?

[image]

**EDIT**: Both buttons work!

Comment: Can you post your menu.xml ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Increase your `android:targetSdkVersion` to `14` or higher, as I outline in [this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/06/08/removing-rogue-menus.html).

Comment: Thank's but nope: My project is set to target 15 already. Note: Both buttons are functional.

Comment: @muslidrikk: Just to make sure that we are talking about the same thing, you need to change `android:targetSdkVersion`, not your build target.

Comment: Well... you're right! That was it and I mixed both. Thank's a lot! :-)

Comment: @muslidrikk: Yeah, I really really wish they had not used "target" for both of those things...

Comment: This is not a solution for all versions. It's just saving the day.

Answer (score 0):

I create a menu like that in my app and have some items in a menu.xml that looks like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_main_about"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never|withText"
    android:title="Acerca de"/>
```

Maybe you are supplying some extra or different attributes that cause that behavior. Please try with this to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

In the samples that brings the ActionBarSherlock, one's of these are what you need.